# Remove all whitespace EXCEPT what is contained in the capture group

Tags: javascript, regex

**Regex Dialect**: JavaScript

I have the following capture group `(('|").*?[^\\\2]\2)` that selects a quoted string excluding escaped quotes.

Matches these for example...

```
"Felix's pet"
'Felix\'s pet'
```

However I would now like to remove **all** whitespace from a string **except** anything matching this pattern. Is there perhaps a way to back reference the capture group `\1` and then exclude it from the matches?

I have attempted to do so with my limited RegEx knowledge, but so far it I can only select the space immediately preceding or following the pattern.

I have saved my test script on [regexr](http://www.regexr.com/3cbs5) for convenience if you would like to play around with my example.

**Intended results**:

`key : string` becomes `key:string`

`dragon : "Felix's pet"` becomes `dragon:"Felix's pet"`

`"Hello World" something here "Another String"`

becomes

`"Hello World"somethinghere"Another String"`

etc...

Comment: @anubhava: I disagree with the dupe vote - the accepted answer uses a strategy that only works with the special string structure in that question, and your (better) answer fails with escaped quotes. Voting to reopen.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Fair enough, I am sure there is a better dup but I just couldn't find using my search.

Comment: @SnareChops: Your regex is trying to take escaped quotes into account, but it does so incorrectly (your character class is wrong, and even if it worked, you should consider the case `'foo \\'` where there is a backslash before the closing quote, but it's not an escaping backslash. Would you need to handle such a case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is extremely hard to do with regular expressions. The following works:

```
result = subject.replace(/ (?=(?:(?:\\.|"(?:\\.|[^"\\])*"|[^\\'"])*'(?:\\.|"(?:\\.|[^"'\\])*"|[^\\'])*')*(?:\\.|"(?:\\.|[^"\\])*"|[^\\'])*$)(?=(?:(?:\\.|'(?:\\.|[^'\\])*'|[^\\'"])*"(?:\\.|'(?:\\.|[^'"\\])*'|[^\\"])*")*(?:\\.|'(?:\\.|[^'\\])*'|[^\\"])*$)/g, "");
```

I've built this answer from one [of my earlier answers to a similar, but not identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8376897/20670); therefore I'll refer you to it for an explanation.

You can test it [live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/cD0xX0/1).

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, you can use `String.replace` with [function as parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter). So you define matching groups and then you can replace each of them separately.

You want match *all white spaces*

```
\s+
```

and you need match *all inside quotes*

```
(('|")(?:[^\\]\\\2|.)*?\2)
```

so you combine it together

```
var pattern = /\s+|(('|")(?:[^\\]\\\2|.)*?\2)/g
```

and you write replace statement with **anonymous function as parameter**:

```
var filteredString = notFilteredString.replace(pattern,
        function(match, group1) { return group1 || "" })
```

With each match the function is called to give replace string. The regexp match either white space or content of quote. The content of quote is wrapped as `group1` and the anonymous function returns `group1` if `group1` is matched or nothing `""` for white spaces or any other match.